# Error in timestamp datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run the below query,

```
 select timestamp '01-01-2017 00:00' log_time from dual
```

I get this error

> ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month.

If it is not valid, How to declare `timestamp` datatype in oracle?

Comment: or is it a problem with the online dbms tool? - http://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ANSI timestamp literals, the value must be formatted in the ISO style yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss:

```
select timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00' log_time 
from dual;
```

Alternatively use Oracle's `to_timestamp()` function if you want to keep that format:

```
select to_timestamp('01-01-2017 00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') log_time 
from dual
```